# Array won't be passed to function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameter-passing

The program is stuck in a loop. I checked it with the debugger, and found out, that my array isn't being passed from my main function to the "binarysearch" function, and from there, it won't be passed to the "check" function. 
`smallestwrh = binarysearch(h, n, contentmax);`
won't pass to
`long long binarysearch(long long *h1, int n, long long contentmax)` 
The Visual Studio Debugger tells me that in the "binarysearch" function h1 is: +h1  0x0171c2bc {-3689348814741910324}   __int64 * 
I also get this stack related error message, but I'm not sure if this would be the cause of my problem: **"Function uses '800048' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap."** 
Full code:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream be("buldo.in");
ofstream ki("buldo.out");

bool check(long long *h2, int n, long long H) {
    //igazat küld vissza amennyiben a H magasságra le lehet lapítani a földet
    int i; long long content = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (h2[i] > H)
            content += h2[i] - H;
        else {
            if (content >= H - h2[i])
                content -= H - h2[i];
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

long long binarysearch(long long *h1, int n, long long contentmax) {
    long long left, right, middle;
    left = 1; right = contentmax; middle = (left + right) / 2;
    while (left < right) {
        if (check(h1, n, middle) == true) {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else {
            right = middle;
        }
    }
    return right;
}

int main() {
    int n, i; long long h[100001], H, sum = 0, contentmax, smallestwrh;
    be >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        be >> h[i];
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        sum += h[i];
    contentmax = (sum / n) + 1; //a legnagyobb földtartalom ami elfér a buldózernél a magasságok számtani átlaga
    smallestwrh = binarysearch(h, n, contentmax); //megkeresi a legkisebb magasságot amire nem működik
    ki << smallestwrh - 1;
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: "and found out, that my array isn't being passed from my main function to the "binarysearch" function, and from there, it won't be passed to the "check" function" That is not true, why do you believe that?

Comment: When I check h1 via the Visual Studio debugger, it doesn't display the elements of h, only one big negative number. (+h1 0x0171c2bc {-3689348814741910324} __int64 * )

Comment: In C/C++ arrays are enumerated from zero. You do not initialize h[0]. Thus you get some random value like -3689348814741910324. You do not access h[0], so technically it might be correct.  But better to  fix this. You get warning about stack size because long h[100001] is 800008 bytes. You are sugessted to use dynamic memory. `std::vector` would be best choice for you. You may allocate vector after you get know `n`. Do not forget to pass it by reference.

Comment: I know that arrays are enumarated from 0. When I check my h array in the main function, the 0th number is a big negative number(because I indexed from 1), after which there are 4 integers, and more big negative numbers. However when I check h1 in the function, there aren't multiple numbers, just a big negative one.(So my 4 integers, and the other unindexed spaces are gone for some reason).

Comment: I'm using the built-in visual studio debugger.

Comment: But if the debugger is displaying the array incorrectly, what may cause the program to be stuck in a loop?

Comment: Askold Ilvento I don't see how a vector could help me, because I can't change the array, and I need the whole array to check the possibilities. Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: Unless you are doing it to learn, or can't use it for some standards requirement, I strongly suggest using the canned binary search functions in <algorithm>

Comment: Unfortunately I need to write my own binary search here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correctly passing the complete array to binarysearch (or at least the start address and the length), you only have a debugging display issue.

In main you have `h`, an array of 100001 `long long`, so the debugger displays `h` as an array. When calling `binarysearch` you do an array to pointer decay, you are only passing the address of the array and losing the information that it is an array and how long it is. So in `binarysearch` the debugger cannot know that the function was called with an array, it must assume that only a pointer to one element was passed. Therefor the debugger only shows the address in `h1` and the value that is stored at `*h1` (which is the first element of `h`).

If you want to see the complete array, you can go to the "Watch" window and add a "h1,[n]". This tells the debugger to display `h1` as an array containing `n` elements. Another less comfortable option is to open the "Memory" window and set the address to `h1`.

For your case another option might be to not do the array to pointer decay. You could create a `std::vector<long long> h;` and pass this by reference to `long long binarysearch(std::vector<long long>& h1, long long contentmax)`. Two advantages: a `vector` can grow dynamically, so you don't have a buffer overflow when the user enters a number `n` higher than 100001, and a `vector` always is data + length, so you just pass it around as one parameter and the length is always correct (`vector_variable.size()` is then the replacement for `n` in `binarysearch`).

Comment: Thank you! However this only makes me more confused. If the array is correctly passed, what may cause the program to be in a loop?(or at least in a loop like state)

Comment: A bug in your code could cause your program to be in a loop.

Comment: @DaniSuba I bet that `while (left < right) {` stays true because you come to a point where you either always have `if (check(h1, n, middle) == true)` or always have the `else`. Side note: your `binaryseach` is not doing a binary search. `check` is checking the complete array. That is not what a binary search is doing. A binary search is only looking at the middle element and then deciding whether to look at the left or at the right part in the next step. Nevertheless, finding the bug should be another question on SO, not an edit to this already answered question.

Comment: Thank you Werner! I just noticed thanks to you that I forgot to put the ```middle=(l+r)/2``` in the while loop!